# How can I make a vim fold expression for PHP stack traces?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, vim, xdebug

I'm using xdebug to produce stack traces in my Wordpress debug.log, and it gives me these stack traces that look like this:

```
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/wp-admin/index.php:0
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   2. wp_dashboard() /var/www/wp-admin/index.php:125
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   3. do_meta_boxes() /var/www/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php:149
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   4. call_user_func() /var/www/wp-admin/includes/template.php:924
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   5. wp_dashboard_site_activity() /var/www/wp-admin/includes/template.php:924
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   6. wp_dashboard_recent_posts() /var/www/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php:538
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   7. WP_Query->__construct() /var/www/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php:587
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   8. WP_Query->query() /var/www/wp-includes/query.php:3352
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP   9. WP_Query->get_posts() /var/www/wp-includes/query.php:3246
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP  10. apply_filters_ref_array() /var/www/wp-includes/query.php:3046
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP  11. call_user_func_array() /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php:256
[02-May-2014 16:35:14 UTC] PHP  12. ShareADraft->the_posts_intercept() /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php:256
```

I can match `PHP Stack trace:` OK in vim, but I need some way for matching all lines that match `PHP <some space here> <some number>.`. I can match the line, but I don't know the syntax for matching all of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for matching all occurrences of `PHP <some space here> <some number>.`

```
/\vPHP\s{-}\d+\.
```